# Smart Tab and newline-and-indent

Tags: indentation, spacemacs

I have the following customizations in my .spacemacs file

```
(defun dotspacemacs/layers ()
   dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(smart-tabs-mode))

(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()

  (setq-default font-latex-fontify-script nil)

  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (setq indent-tabs-mode t
                    indent-line-function 'indent-relative)
              (smart-tabs-mode-enable)
              (smart-tabs-advice indent-relative tab-width)
              (electric-indent-mode -1)
              )))
  )
```

I use indent-relative since Latex-mode does not use tabs at all apparently (see [How can I configure AUCTeX to use tab characters for leading indentation?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14820)).

If, in LaTeX-mode, I indent a line with an indentation that starts with a tab and is followed by spaces, and then hit Enter + Tab, `smart-tabs-mode` takes care that the next line will be indented exactly the same way, i.e. the combination of tabs and spaces ist preserved.

However, if I use `newline-and-indent` to get a newline (or leave `electric-indent-mode` on), the indentation is spaces only. Is that a limitation of `smart-tabs-mode` or am I missing something?