# Making AUCTeX use tabs for leading indentation doesn't work

Tags: latex, indentation, auctex, tabs

[This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14840/14203) says how to make AUCTeX use tabs for leading indentation. However, it doesn't work for me and I don't understand why it doesn't.

After adding the code to my init file, LaTeX-mode just stopped indenting altogether.

I suspected that's because I customized variable and removed the LaTeX-mode- and indentation-related lines

```
 '(LaTeX-indent-level 4)
 '(LaTeX-item-indent 0)
 '(TeX-brace-indent-level 4)
 '(indent-tabs-mode t)
```

from the block

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(LaTeX-indent-level 4)
 '(LaTeX-item-indent 0)
 '(TeX-brace-indent-level 4)
 '(indent-tabs-mode t)
 '(org-agenda-files
   (quote
    (<I censored the strings in here.>)))
 '(org-file-apps
   (quote
    ((auto-mode . emacs)
     ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
     ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
     ("\\.pdf\\'" . "evince %s"))))
 '(safe-local-variable-values (quote ((TeX-master . t))))
 '(show-paren-mode t)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

in my init file after backing `~/.emacs.d` up as the comments say I'm not supposed to modify that block by hand. LaTeX mode still didn't indent (at all), so I had to remove the code I got from the linked answer and go back to indentation via spaces.

How do I get indentation via tabs working?

---

### Update

After removing the customization with Andrew Swann's help and adding the code stated in the linked answer back to my init file, AUCTeX still doesn't use tabs for indentation. Or rather: It doesn't seem to indent anything. I tried setting `LaTeX-indent-level` to 4 and `LaTeX-item-indent` to 0 and even setting `LaTeX-item-indent` to 4, too. It still didn't indent.

When I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, however, it actually enters a tab character.

Comment: You can modify those settings via the customization interface: `M-x customize` or `M-x customize-variable`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I know how I can customize the values of those variables but not how I can reset them to their default values so `customize` deletes those lines from the init file. That's why I tried simply deleting the lines to see whether it worked would I be able to reset those variables properly.

Comment: The customize interface has the option to clear the customization resetting to the standard varibale.  This is under the options from the "State" button.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thank you. Resetting the variables worked but the indentation still doesn't. I updated the question.

Comment: What is TAB key bound to? Issue C-x k TAB

Comment: @giordano I suppose you mean `C-h k TAB`, not `C-x k TAB`. It's bound to this: https://pastebin.com/HFKrBiJ3

Comment: Yes, I meant `C-h k`.  What's the value of `indent-line-function` in a LaTeX buffer?  Issue `C-h v indent-line-function RET`

Comment: @giordano Its value is `LaTeX-indent-line`.

Comment: So the hook I proposed in the linked answer isn't running?

Comment: @giordano Oh, I'm sorry. I forgot that I added the customization back in and removed your code so I could continue editing LaTeX files. I now removed the customization and added your code back to my init file. `TAB` is still bound to the same but `indent-line-function` now has the value `indent-relative`. `indent-tabs-mode` is `t`, too, so your hook works. When I use `TAB`, tabs are entered. When I hit `C-c C-e RET` to create an itemize list, however, there is no indentation of the item (even when I customize `LaTeX-item-indent` to `4`).

Comment: Basically, your original problem is solved, right?  Anyway, the function `indent-relative` doesn't know `LaTeX-item-indent`.  AUCTeX isn't really designed to use tabs for indentation, most probably because few people use them and requested such feature.

Comment: The original problem is to "[make] AUCTeX use tabs for leading indentation". This simply removed all leading indentation. I want list items to be indented by 1 tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this minimal `init.el`, it works for me:

```el
;; --- This is just the MELPA setup to fetch auctex ---
(require 'package)
(let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                    (not (gnutls-available-p))))
       (url (concat (if no-ssl "http" "https") "://melpa.org/packages/")))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" url) t))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)

;; --- Remove the indent-line-function overwrite
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))

(custom-set-variables
 '(LaTeX-indent-level 4)
 '(LaTeX-item-indent 4)
 '(TeX-brace-indent-level 4)
 '(indent-tabs-mode t)
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (auctex))))
```

If you want the tab to be 4 spaces wide, you can `M-x customize-variable RET tab-width` and set it to 4.

So, the customizations are:

- Set `indent-tabs-mode` for LaTeX:

  ```el
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))
  ```
- Customize indent sizes for LaTeX:

  ```el
   '(LaTeX-indent-level 4)
   '(LaTeX-item-indent 4)
   '(TeX-brace-indent-level 4)
   '(indent-tabs-mode t)
  ```

Comment: Now I'm very confused. I copied everything from `;; --- Remove the indent-line-function overwrite` downwards into my init file. Then AUCTeX suddenly actually used tabs for leading indentation. Great. But the automatically created comments say I'm not supposed to have more than 1 `custom-set-variables` variables block, so I made sure I set all the variables but the last one in your `custom-set-variables` block to what you set them to. I didn't figure out how to set the last one using `M-x RET customize-set-variable`, so I removed all but the last (and very first, of course) line of your ...

Comment: ... `custom-set-variables`  block and left the `add-hook` block above as it was. It then stopped working. AUXTeC went back to using spaces. Why doesn't it work when I try to use `M-x RET customize-set-variable`? If it needs to be in the same `custom-set-variables` block, how do I generate the last line using `M-x RET customize-set-variable`? (Because the automatically created comments say one should do it that way and not edit the block directly.)

Comment: I'm guessing you mean, by the last line of `custom-set-variables`, this one: `(package-selected-packages ...`, right? That was just added automatically when I installed AUCTeX (`M-x package-install RET auctex RET`), but you shouldn't worry about that because there's probably already another block with `package-selected-packages` and `auctex` inside somewhere.

Comment: The only changes that *should* be made are the code blocks at the end; the first one somewhere in your init file and the last one as customizations. So...honestly if that doesn't work I'm out of guesses too :/ (as I can't reproduce your setup here)

Comment: I think something with my `TeX-brace-indent-level` was wrong because I was able to remove all the other lines without it stopping to work. After setting it again via `customize`, the block was removed from my init file automatically whilst customizing. After setting the tab width to 4, it inserted 2 tabs. So I customized `LaTeX-item-indent` to 0 and it now works as I wanted it to. Thank you.