# Manual indentation in LaTeX mode

Tags: latex, indentation

I'm new to Emacs, and dislike the default indentation in LaTeX mode. I want the indentation to do the following:

- insert a \t character (not spaces)
- be completely manual (I want to have to press Tab on each line to indent, rather than to have Emacs automatically make it match the previous line)
- display the \t characters as 4 spaces.

Essentially, I want Emacs to behave the same way as MS Notepad, XFCE's Mousepad or Vim do by default with respect to indentation (after setting \t to be displayed as 4 spaces).

I got close to this result by using the following .emacs file (taken from [this q/a](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14820/how-can-i-configure-auctex-to-use-tab-characters-for-leading-indentation/14840#14840)):

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq indent-tabs-mode t
              indent-line-function 'indent-relative)))
```

But it causes the following (strange) problem: if I type something like

```
\begin{thm}[Liouville 1851]
```

followed by pressing Return and Tab, it indents all the way to the "1" in "1851". I suspect this has something to do with the 'indent-relative, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Do anyone know how I can make Emacs indentation work this way, without having the above problem? Any help is highly appreciated.

-Aleks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what `indent-relative` does. I think what you want instead is `tab-to-tab-stop`. You'll also need your tab stops set to 4 spaces for this:

```el
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq indent-tabs-mode t
              indent-line-function 'tab-to-tab-stop
              tab-width 4)))
```

If you're still getting automatic indentation, make sure you have turned off `electric-indent-mode`. You can add that to the hook as:

```el
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq indent-tabs-mode t
              indent-line-function 'tab-to-tab-stop
              tab-width 4
              electric-indent-mode nil)))
```

Comment: This unfortunately causes Emacs to indent new lines (regardless of whether the previous line is indented). I want Emacs to _never_ indent a new line unless I hit tab, and when I hit tab I want Emacs to indent by exactly one \t at a time. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: There's a lot of different ways to tweak indentation, it's a bit of a puzzle to find them all! I think electric-indent-mode might be the next wrinkle.

Comment: Thanks! Disabling electric-indent-mode makes Emacs behave exactly as I want it to.